# How do i get the result of a adaptive card?

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to get the result of my AdaptiveCard.
My bot uses waterfalldialogs. In one Waterfallstep i present the user a number of Rooms with the time and date. The user then can choose a room. I tried it like shown below. Sadly the `activity` stays null. How do I get the result of the adaptive card

```cs
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> AfterChoice(WaterfallStepContext step, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (step.Result is Activity activity && activity.Value != null && ((dynamic)activity.Value).chosenRoom is JValue chosenRoom)
    {
        dynamic requestedBooking = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>((string)chosenRoom.Value);
        this.roomemail = requestedBooking.roomEmail;
        return await step.EndDialogAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        return await step.BeginDialogAsync(whatever, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

How do I get the users choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adaptive Cards send their Submit results a little different than regular user text. When a user types in the chat and sends a normal message, it ends up in `Context.Activity.Text`. When a user fills out an input on an Adaptive Card, it ends up in `Context.Activity.Value`, which is an object where the key names are the `id` in your card and the values are the field values in the adaptive card.

For example, the json:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Test Adaptive Card"
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Text:"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": 20
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "id": "userText",
                            "placeholder": "Enter Some Text"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": 80
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Submit"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

.. creates a card that looks like:

[image: Test Adaptive Card]

If a user enters "Testing Testing 123" in the text box and hits Submit, `Context.Activity` will look something like:

```
{ type: 'message',
  value: { userText: 'Testing Testing 123' },
  from: { id: 'xxxxxxxx-05d4-478a-9daa-9b18c79bb66b', name: 'User' },
  locale: '',
  channelData: { postback: true },
  channelId: 'emulator',
  conversation: { id: 'xxxxxxxx-182b-11e9-be61-091ac0e3a4ac|livechat' },
  id: 'xxxxxxxx-182b-11e9-ad8e-63b45e3ebfa7',
  localTimestamp: 2019-01-14T18:39:21.000Z,
  recipient: { id: '1', name: 'Bot', role: 'bot' },
  timestamp: 2019-01-14T18:39:21.773Z,
  serviceUrl: 'http://localhost:58453' }
```

The user submission can be seen in `Context.Activity.Value.userText`.

Note that adaptive card submissions are sent as a postBack, which means that the submission data doesn't appear in the chat window as part of the conversation--it stays on the Adaptive Card.

**Using Adaptive Cards with [Waterfall Dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#waterfall-dialogs)**

Your question doesn't quite relate to this, but since you may end up attempting this, I thought it might be important to include in my answer.

Natively, Adaptive Cards don't work like prompts. With a prompt, the prompt will display and wait for user input before continuing. But with Adaptive Cards (even if it contains an input box and a submit button), there is no code in an Adaptive Card that will cause a Waterfall Dialog to wait for user input before continuing the dialog.

So, if you're using an Adaptive Card that takes user input, you generally want to handle whatever the user submits outside of the context of a Waterfall Dialog.

That being said, if you want to use an Adaptive Card as part of a Waterfall Dialog, there is a workaround. Basically, you:

1. Display the Adaptive Card
2. Display a Text Prompt
3. Convert the user's Adaptive Card input into the input of a Text Prompt

In your Waterfall Dialog class (steps 1 and 2):

```cs
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> DisplayCardAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Create the Adaptive Card
    var cardPath = Path.Combine(".", "AdaptiveCard.json");
    var cardJson = File.ReadAllText(cardPath);
    var cardAttachment = new Attachment()
    {
        ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cardJson),
    };

    // Create the text prompt
    var opts = new PromptOptions
    {
        Prompt = new Activity
        {
            Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { cardAttachment },
            Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
            Text = "waiting for user input...", // You can comment this out if you don't want to display any text. Still works.
        }
    };

    // Display a Text Prompt and wait for input
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), opts);
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> HandleResponseAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Do something with step.result
    // Adaptive Card submissions are objects, so you likely need to JObject.Parse(step.result)
    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync($"INPUT: {stepContext.Result}");
    return await stepContext.NextAsync();
}
```

In your main bot class (`<your-bot>.cs`) (step 3):

```cs
var activity = turnContext.Activity;

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activity.Text) && activity.Value != null)
{
    activity.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does it have to be type string? I'm showing the user a number of different types of rooms(my adaptive Card is using Input.Choice not Input.Text). I have stored them in an Array that has a title and a value. The title Shows the room and starttime and endtime of the booking (start and endtime in short form) as a string. The value part holds the starttime and endtime in the form of iso8601 as a DateTime and the roomEmail as a string. The value part is Serialized into json. I want to get the users choice, so i get the start-, endtime and the roomemail.

Comment: I tried your tutorial. Problem is when I write a message that is before the DisplayCardStepAsync. I get a NullReferenceException, because  the `var channelData =…` at the 3rd step. Is the Prompt necessary? Isn't it possible to just replace the `var postbackactivity`with an Activity Attribute? That way I can skip the TextPrompt and I can use my AfterChoice method with the activity Attribute.

Comment: @MaxRowe It does not have to be a text box input; you can use the choice input. However, all input will get converted to a string in `postbackActivity.Value`. Ah, it could be because `channelData` is null on some of the other user text. You could use `if (channelData != null && channelData.ContainsKey("postback"))`. The prompt is only necessary if you want to use the user input on the adaptive card in the next waterfall step. An adaptive card doesn't wait for user input, so if you need your waterfall to wait, a text prompt after the card is the way to go.

Comment: Really, the important part to remember is that all user input on adaptive cards gets passed in as a `postBack` (meaning it's invisible to the user) in `<whatever>activity.Value` and that to use it in any way, you have to grab it from there. It's easiest to grab it in the `OnTurnAsync` method.

Comment: The NullReferenceException is thrown one line earlier. When I define `channelData`. The line tries to make a string of something that's empty :(.

Comment: I don't have a bot up and running to test this, but I've edited the code to remove the NullReferenceException. If you're still getting one after the change, let me know.

Comment: I've tested this and got it working just fine. If yours still has issues after using the above code, start a new StackOverflow issue, paste your `OnTurnAsync` code in it, and add the link here and I can help you further. Good luck!