# How do I handle Postback from AdaptiveCard in OnTurnAsync-Method

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, adaptive-cards

I'm programming a bot that is using adaptive Cards ChoiceSet. Im trying to get the users choice. Now because the result doesnt Show in the Chat, I have to check in the `OnTurnAsync`-Method, if the Message I get is a `postback`.
How do i do this? 
This is how I tried -> Null ReferenceException at 
 `if (dc.Context.Activity.GetType().GetProperty("ChannelData") != null)`

## Edit from Botframework Support: Please do not use the code block below. It only works in Emulator. Instead, use:

```cs
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activity.Text) && activity.Value != null)
{
    activity.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity.Value);
}
```

My OnTurnAsync-Method:

```
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        DialogContext dc = null;

        switch (turnContext.Activity.Type)
        {
            case ActivityTypes.Message:
                if (dc.Context.Activity.GetType().GetProperty("ChannelData") != null)
                {
                    var channelData = JObject.Parse(dc.Context.Activity.ChannelData.ToString());
                    if (channelData.ContainsKey("postback"))
                    {
                        var postbackActivit = dc.Context.Activity;
                        postbackActivit.Text = postbackActivit.Value.ToString();
                        await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(postbackActivit);
                    }
                }

                await ProcessInputAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                break;
```

Comment: Note that this is related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54747337/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-adaptive-card/54755430

Comment: sorry i didn't mark the answer yet. I'm still working on the problem. The postback works  I get the answer of the adaptive Card. I'm having Problems with the waterfall dialogs. I can't seem to get step.result from the previous step. I think it's because mutliple Dialogs are created… [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54901150/how-does-turncontext-respond-work-using-waterfalldialogs)

Comment: No problem! Glad you got that part working! I, or somebody on my team, will take a look at your new issue today. Hopefully we get you going!

Comment: Got a new issue :( [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54922076/cant-get-passed-login-dialog-from-botbuild-samples)

Comment: Somebody on my team will help you with that (probably me). FYI: So long as you use the `botframework` tag on your question, somebody on the Bot Framework team will get assigned to it to help you!

Comment: Ah good to know. Because there is no way i'll figure out the next problem by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of your line: `DialogContext dc = null`.

It should be: `var dc = await Dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext);`

Note that `Dialogs` might need to be replaced with whatever you defined your `DialogSet` with. There's a few different ways to do it, but here's the upper half of my `<myBot>.cs` class that I used to test your previous issue:

```cs
public class QuickTestBot_CSharpBot : IBot
    {
        private readonly IStatePropertyAccessor<DialogState> _dialogStateAccessor;
        private readonly ConversationState _conversationState;
        public QuickTestBot_CSharpBot(ConversationState conversationState)
        {
            _conversationState = conversationState ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(conversationState));
            _dialogStateAccessor = _conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState));

            Dialogs = new DialogSet(_dialogStateAccessor);
            Dialogs.Add(new QuickDialog());

        }

        private DialogSet Dialogs { get; set; }

        public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var activity = turnContext.Activity;

            var dc = await Dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activity.Text))
            {
                activity.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity.Value);
            }
    [...]
```

Here's some links to a few good samples that also use Waterfall Dialogs, so you can see how they set up their `<bot>.cs` class (note that they don't get input from adaptive cards...this is just to help  you set up your waterfall dialog and `OnTurnAsync`):

1. [MultiTurnPromptsBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt/MultiTurnPromptsBot.cs)
2. [CardsBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/06.using-cards/CardsBot.cs)
3. [BasicBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.basic-bot)